# Где проводить инициализацию

Tags: angular2, typescript

Angular 6. Back-end на ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI. Хочу заполнить поле `paginationHelper` класса при обращении к компоненту. Сервис возвращает список пользователей.

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  paginationHelper: PaginationHelper<UserResponse>;

  constructor(public _userService: UserApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.GetUsers()
      .subscribe(data => this.paginationHelper = data);
  }
}
```

Тут `paginationHelper` undefined, но если объявить переменную в этом же методе, то она заполниться `data` из сервиса:

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  paginationHelper: PaginationHelper<UserResponse>;

  constructor(public _userService: UserApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let ph: PaginationHelper<UserResponse>;
    this._userService.GetUsers()
      .subscribe(data => ph = data);
  }
}
```

---

```
export class PaginationHelper<T> {
    Entities: T[];
    PageNumber: number;
    PageSize: number;
    TotalPages: number;
}
```

---

```
export class UserResponse {
    Id: string;
    FullName: string;
    Login: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
}
```

---

```
<h1>List of users</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Login</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of paginationHelper.Entities">
      <td>{{user.FullName}}</td>
      <td>{{user.Login}}</td>
      <td>{{user.PhoneNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{user.Id}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
  <li>Page: {{paginationHelper.PageNumber}}</li>
  <li>Page Size: {{paginationHelper.PageSize}}</li>
  <li>Total Pages: {{paginationHelper.TotalPages}}</li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Представьте ещё код класса PaginationHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Core со своими дефолтными конфигурациями возвращает вам json объект в котором все поля названы с маленькой буквы. То бишь когда вы присваиваете своей локальной переменной дату из json респонса, весь объект перетирается и поля у нового называеются уже не FullName а fullName.

Варианта два:

- либо переконфигурировать бэк
- либо поменять свою модель
  UserResponse(назвать все переменные с маленькой буквы)